# Convert four combination of Boolean into true/false - With IF Else statement

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, boolean-operations

I actually try to convert four different Boolean into true/false.

My case is,

```
   True false false false Then true else false
   false True false false Then true else false
   false false True false Then true else false
   false false false True Then true else false
```

I tried like this,

```
int a=1;
int b=0;
int c=0;
int d=0;

int cnt=0;

// A block of code will be executed only when any one of the four variables is 1 and
//the rest of them is 0. and another block will be executed when the above mentioned
//condition become false.

if (a==0) { cnt+=1; }
if (b==0) { cnt+=1; }
if (c==0) { cnt+=1; }
if (d==0) { cnt+=1; }

if (cnt==3) { // true block } else { //false block }
```

The above code is working perfectly fine, But i had taken a challenge to check this condition in a single if statement. Then i tried like this.

```
if(!((!(a==0) && !(b==0)) &&  (!(c==0) && !(d==0))))
{
   //true block
}
else
{
   //false block
}
```

The above condition is failing in some combinations(a=1 b=0 c=1 d=1). Can anybody point out what the issue is.? or suggest any new ideas.?

```
My objective is convert (3 false + 1 true) into true other wise into false.
```

[**Note:** I just gave the scenario for understanding purpose only. a,b,c,d value may be differ. See my objective. Don't say answers in favor of 1 and 0]

Comment: why don't you sum a + b + c + d to see if equals to 1

Comment: `false` is different from `0` in Java. What do you have? 0, 1 or true, false?

Comment: @Maroun That would also be true if more than one variable would be true

Comment: @MarounMaroun. That will be true even for 1 false value. That's not what OP want.

Comment: @user2310289. Only if negative value is not a possibility.

Comment: @user2310289 Sorry, i just gave this case for understanding. But there is possibility for that variables may be differ.

Comment: @RajaPrabhuOfficial. Please tell us whether your values are numerical  or boolean?

Comment: It's not too difficult to see the problem here, but it always helps to be more specific than "is failing in some combinations", by giving some sample input with actual and expected output, for example. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) also helps.

Comment: @RajaPrabhuOfficial then update your question to explain better

Comment: Question updated. with additional notes.

Comment: You are stating that if at least (or exactly?) one of your variables is true - then the result is true. What about cases with no or more than one true value (like false true false true) ?

Comment: @tbsalling my case is exactly one of the variable is true then the result is true.

Comment: What's wrong with your check: `!(!(a==0) && !(b==0) && !(c==0) && !(d==0))` = `(a==0) || (b==0) || (c==0) || (d==0))` = true whenever one of them is 0.

Comment: @Dukeling But he wants it to resolve to false when more than one is 0.

Comment: @Johanneke I'm saying what's wrong, not how to fix it (or it would be an answer).

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, I misread. By the way, @RajaPrabhuOfficial, I recommend writing your checks 'as simple as possible', so no double negatives. Look at Dukeling's comment and see how he rewrote your check to the much more readable `(a==0) || (b==0) || (c==0) || (d==0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
    boolean a = true;
    boolean b = false;
    boolean c = false;
    boolean d = false;

    if ((a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 1 : 0) + (c ? 1 : 0) + (d ? 1 : 0) == 1) {
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }
```

[edit]... or here's another way to do it :

```
    if ((a ^ b ^ c ^ d) & ((a & b) == (c & d))) {
        System.out.println("**XOR** You win!");
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be a nice answer. wait i'll check and come back to you..!

Comment: !((a & b) ^ (c & d)) can be converted to ((a & b) == (c & d))

Answer (score 5):

I think I would use the following method, which makes the algorithm reusable and support any number of arguments. It returns true only if exactly one argument was true.

```
private boolean oneTrue(boolean... args){
    boolean found = false;

    for (boolean arg : args) {
        if(found && arg){
            return false;
        }
        found |= arg;
    }
    return found;
}
```

You can test it like this:

```
private void test(){

    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = true;
    boolean c = false;
    boolean d = false;

    System.out.println(oneTrue(a,b,c,d));
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I like that you made it useful for any number of arguments, and the code is much clearer than a big if-statement with a bunch or || or &&.

Comment: You know, i just learnt a new concept from you. By the way i would like to up vote your answer.

Comment: +1 This is much more readable and flexible than the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Shortest pure bool solution which I can suggest:

```
System.out.println((a | b) ^ (c | d)) & ((a ^ b) | (c ^ d));
```

But in your program already already used 1 and 0, if it variables always 1 and 0, you may not use boolean just use following:

```
if (a + b + c + d == 1)
{
  // true
} else
{
  // false
}
```

if this varibales may have any values. In this case I recommend convert it to 1 and 0 instead of boolean and again can simply calculate sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression:

```
a && !(b || c || d) ||
b && !(a || c || d) ||
c && !(a || b || d) ||
d && !(a || b || c)
```